Mediatr CQRS using generics in C#
Why can't the call to create an instance of the Mediatr command in the following code work? It can't seem to find the proper instance of the generic. Basically it's specifically looking for MyCustomCommand**<CustomPayload1> implementation. How do I fix my command declaration for the generics to work? Thank you
Edit: The actual exception I'm getting is No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler2[MyCustomCommand1[CustomPayload1],CustomResponse]' has been registered.
[Calling client code]
.
.
.
var myCmd = new MyCustomCommand<CustomPayload1>(param1, param2, ...);
var response = await _mediator.Send(myCmd);
.
.
.


[Command declarations]

public interface ICustomPayload
{...}

public class CustomPayload1 : ICustomPayload
{...}

public class CustomPayload2 : ICustomPayload
{...}

public record MyCustomCommand<T> : IRequest<CustomResponse>
    where T : ICustomPayload, new()
{...}


may be problem with param1,param2 when you use, new() ?

Thanks, but definitely not an issue with the command ctor parameters

try this await _mediator.Send((ICustomPayload) myCmd), I think mediatR register T as ICustomPayload or you have bad handler declaration

Thanks daremachine. myCmd is of type MyCustomCommand not ICustomPayload

Still stuck at this error message
